# Build planter with just one box?

Tags: containers, concrete

Most of the DIY examples describe how to make a concrete planter with two boxes (a big box and a smaller box).

I only have one cardboard box, and the closest store is far away.

Can I build a planter/pot with just one cardboard box?

Comment: Are you talking about using the cardboard boxes as forms for the concrete? Pour some concrete into the bottom of a big box, rest the smaller box on top of it, then pour more concrete in the gap between the two?

Comment: I’m asking about using just one cardboard box.

Comment: You need one box to contain the concrete while it sets, and another box to make a hole where the soil will go. Trying to use cardboard boxes rather than wood for either of those functions probably isn't going to work, since concrete is heavy and wet!